# How could I convert a pom xml to sbt dependencies?

Tags: sbt, pom.xml

I have some projects that have all the **dependencies** stored inside **pom.xml** files.

How could I retrieve the dependencies from inside so I could easily place them to a project that uses sbt?

Copy pasting all of them is just time consuming..

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This scala script, which runs from command line, takes care of that, converting the pom.xml file to sbt dependencies printed on screen. Then you only need to copy paste once for each pom.xml file.

Note: the pom.xml must be in the same folder as the script. Then from command line you execute: `scala scriptname.scala`

```
import scala.xml._

(XML.load("pom.xml") \\ "dependencies") \ "dependency" foreach ((dependency: Node) => {
val groupId = (dependency \ "groupId").text
val artifactId = (dependency \ "artifactId").text
val version = (dependency \ "version").text
val scope = (dependency \ "scope").text
val classifier = (dependency \ "classifier").text
val artifactValName: String = artifactId.replaceAll("[-\\.]", "_")

print("val %s = \"%s\" %% \"%s\" %% \"%s\"".format(artifactValName, groupId, artifactId, version))
scope match {
  case "" => print("\n")
  case _ => print(" %% \"%s\"\n".format(scope))
}
None
});
```

Comment: @George Pligor I adapted this a little to create a Seq of dependencies (with my own bug added). I made it Apache 2.0 if any comment please let me know :) https://github.com/matanster/pomToSbt

Comment: thx! I added the possibility to pass the pom file argument using amm: https://gist.github.com/dportabella/3512f92a60325d8375e5ceb942b911da

Comment: I'm getting below error. 

scala PomToSbt.scala
/root/PomToSbt.scala:14: error: ';' expected but string literal found.
    case _ => s""" % "$scope""""
               ^
/root/PomToSbt.scala:17: error: ';' expected but string literal found.
  s"""  "$groupId" %% "$artifactId" % "$version"$scope2"""
   ^
two errors found

Comment: @AkshatChaturvedi you are free to try and edit the answer to send a better version that is up to date and works also for you and for others

Answer (score 8):

I've enhanced George Pligor's answer (and fixed a few bugs) so a complete `build.sbt` file is created that incorporates the dependencies from `pom.xml`. To convert a Maven `pom.xml` to `build.sbt`:

1. Place this code into a file called `PomToSbt.scala` next to `pom.xml`
2. Type `scala PomToSbt.scala > build.sbt`
3. The dependencies from `pom.xml` will be extracted and placed into a complete `build.sbt` file.

Here is the code:

```
import scala.xml._

val lines = (XML.load("pom.xml") \\ "dependencies") \ "dependency" map { dependency => 
  val groupId = (dependency \ "groupId").text
  val artifactId = (dependency \ "artifactId").text
  val version = (dependency \ "version").text
  val scope = (dependency \ "scope").text
  val classifier = (dependency \ "classifier").text
  val artifactValName: String = artifactId.replaceAll("[-\\.]", "_")

  val scope2 = scope match {
    case "" => ""
    case _ => s""" % "$scope""""
  }

  s"""  "$groupId" %% "$artifactId" % "$version"$scope2"""
}

val buildSbt = io.Source.fromURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mslinn/sbtTemplate/master/build.sbt").mkString
val libText = "libraryDependencies ++= Seq("
val buildSbt2 = buildSbt.replace(libText, libText + lines.mkString("\n", ",\n", ""))
println(buildSbt2)
```

[I made a gist](https://gist.github.com/mslinn/21684f1e5da630dfd734); if any updates are required I will make them there.

Comment: thx! I added the possibility to pass the pom file argument using amm: https://gist.github.com/dportabella/3512f92a60325d8375e5ceb942b911da

Answer (score 2):

Mike, here's the code that works with Scala 11 at least:

```
import scala.xml._

//build.sbt file
val lines = (XML.load("pom.xml") \\ "dependencies") \ "dependency" map { dependency =>
  val groupId = (dependency \ "groupId").text
  val artifactId = (dependency \ "artifactId").text
  val version = (dependency \ "version").text
  val scope = (dependency \ "scope").text
  val classifier = (dependency \ "classifier").text
  val artifactValName: String = artifactId.replaceAll("[-\\.]", "_")

  val scope2 = scope match {
    case "" => ""
    case _ => s""" % "$scope""""
  }

  s"""  "$groupId" %% "$artifactId" % "$version"$scope2"""
}

val buildSbt: String = io.Source.fromURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mslinn/sbtTemplate/master/build.sbt").mkString

val libText = "libraryDependencies ++= Seq\\("
val buildSbt2 = buildSbt.replaceFirst(libText, libText + lines.mkString("\n", ",\n", ""))
println(buildSbt2)
```

Answer (score 1):

This [blog entry](http://blog.wandledi.org/post/27780639582/if-only-i-knew-better-using-pom-xml-in-sbt) explains one possible way. There's a comment pointing to a plugin that handles more complex cases.

Comment: Here's the relevant link, which worked for me: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-pom-reader

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.xml._
// To convert a Maven pom.xml to build.sbt:
// 1) Place this code into a file called PomToSbt.scala next to pom.xml
// 2) Type scala PomtoSbt.scala > build.sbt
// The dependencies from pom.xml will be extracted and place into a complete build.sbt file
// Because most pom.xml files only refernence non-Scala dependencies, I did not use %%
val lines = (XML.load("pom.xml") \\ "dependencies") \ "dependency" map { dependency => 
  val groupId = (dependency \ "groupId").text
  val artifactId = (dependency \ "artifactId").text
  val version = (dependency \ "version").text
  val scope = (dependency \ "scope").text
  val classifier = (dependency \ "classifier").text
  val artifactValName: String = artifactId.replaceAll("[-\\.]", "_")

  val scope2 = scope match {
    case "" => ""
    case _ => s""" % "$scope""""
  }

  s"""  "$groupId" %  "$artifactId" % "$version"$scope2"""
}

val buildSbt = io.Source.fromURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mslinn/sbtTemplate/master/build.sbt").mkString
val libText = "libraryDependencies ++= Seq("
val buildSbt2 = buildSbt.replace(libText, libText + lines.mkString("\n", ",\n", ""))
println(buildSbt2)
```